# How to calculate regression with dates as x axis?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, regression

Is it good practice for a polynomial regression with dates as x axis to convert the datetime values to numbers, from 1 to the len(dataframe)+1? Are the predicted values considered to be accurate?

```
data['numbered'] = ''
for i in range(1, len(data) + 1):
    data.loc[i - 1, ['numbered']] = i

X = data[['numbered']].values
y = data[['ozone']].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
``
```

Comment: You could certainly do that; though if you use a polynomial regression, overfitting could be a problem, and the result will definitely blow up when you try to predict a date far in the future... Why not use time series models instead?

Comment: "*from 1 to the len(dataframe)+1*" that would mean simply using the index. - If your time series is mono-spaced, i.e. the timedelta between each two data points is equal (dt == const.), it is ok. Otherwise not, since your regression must take into account the "temporal spacing" of your data to be meaningful. I hope that makes sense ;-)

Comment: datetime objects can easily be converted to numeric values (monotonically increasing), e.g. POSIX [seconds since the epoch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) or [Juldate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_julian_date.html#pandas-timestamp-to-julian-date). For data that only spans a day, seconds after midnight is also useful. All these can go straight into your regression model.